# If no response from user, continue script

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation

I have a script that accomplishes such and such a task, and after that is complete I usually give it's output to another script. I would like to circumvent this process and automate it. Possibly by doing:

```
#end of first script's duties

print 'Would you like to run this output into the next script?'
# wait for user input 'yes or no'

# Possibly move on to next script...
```

In the event that the user doesn't give any input within say, 30 seconds, is there a way to have the script just assume 'yes'? Also as a bonus how would I add a countdown timer to the command line? I'm new enough that this seems crazy, but I'm curious how hard this would be to implement. Thanks.

Comment: You would have to use multiple threads to accomplish something like this with messaging between threads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179537/python-wait-x-secs-for-a-key-and-continue-execution-if-not-pressed

Answer (score 1):

Create a thread that reads from the command line. Have the main thread wait 30 seconds for the first thread to complete, waking up at 1 second interval to print the countdown. After 30 seconds of waiting, kill the second thread.

Comment: There's no way to do this within the python script?

Comment: See here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, although stopping a thread is not really a good idea…

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def sleeper():
    raw_input("Would you like to run this output into the next script? ")

t = Thread(target=sleeper)
t.start()

time.sleep(5)
t._Thread__stop()
print "\ntime out"
```