# Shorten sleep time on user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to shorten a `time.sleep(600)` if the user inputs a key, without resorting to some ugly hack like:

```
key_pressed = False
for i in range(600):
    key_pressed = key_was_pressed()
    if not key_pressed:
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: have you considered a listener thread + notify?

Comment: I'll settle for any key (except CTRL-C) but if I can set the key(s), it's even better.

Comment: is it safe to assume Python3? Is the platform (Win/*nix) known in advance? Is this project by chance using tornado?

Comment: Very similar (same?) question was asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179537/python-wait-x-secs-for-a-key-and-continue-execution-if-not-pressed

Comment: Yup, Python3. Windows, but a general solution is always better.

Comment: @d99kris The accepted answer involves busy-waiting, precisely what I want to avoid, as you can see in the ugly hack in my question. (I know `time.sleep()` is technically also busy-waiting, but much less ressource-intensive than a `while True:` loop)

Comment: Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43065186/9504749

Answer (score 11):

This is a cross-platform adaptation of an implementation using `signal.alarm` interrupt (an idea which is not available on Windows). This code should work for Linux, macOS, and Windows. The 3rd-party helper library [`readchar`](https://github.com/magmax/python-readchar) can be installed with `pip install readchar`.

```
import os
import signal
import sys

from threading import Timer
from readchar import readkey

def wait_for(key="x", timeout=600):
    pid = os.getpid()
    sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT if os.name == "nt" else signal.SIGINT
    timer = Timer(timeout, lambda: os.kill(pid, sig))
    print(f"waiting {timeout}s for user to press {key!r} ...")
    timer.start()  # spawn a worker thread to interrupt us later
    while True:
        k = readkey()
        print(f"received {k!r}")
        if k == key:
            timer.cancel()  # cancel the timer
            print("breaking")
            break

def main():
    import sys
    try:
        wait_for(key=sys.argv[1], timeout=int(sys.argv[2]))
    except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
        print("user took too long")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Won't this flood one core with the `while True` loop?

Comment: No.  getch is blocking.

Comment: `readchar.readkey()` doesn't seem to work on Spyder, but if I simulate the user pressing `x`, it works. However, if I do nothing, it doesn't work and I get : `Restarting kernel Bad key "text.kerning_factor" on line 4 in
C:\Users\Francois\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test_patch.mplstyle.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.1.3/matplotlibrc.template
or from the matplotlib source distribution` and after that, retrying in the same console crashes it.

Comment: @FrançoisM.  I am not familiar with spyder. Does this code work directly in Python on your platform?